# How do I get a MethodInfo from an ActionExecutingContext?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

If I have an instance of ActionExecutingContext how might I get the MethodInfo of the 
action in question?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ActionExecutingContext has a property ActionDescriptor.

*If* the return type is actually a ReflectedActionDescriptor you should be able to cast is as such. Once you have a ReflectedActionDescriptor...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.reflectedactiondescriptor.aspx

... you can use it's MethodInfo property...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.reflectedactiondescriptor.methodinfo.aspx

You should be careful using techniques that take the action's name and use this to obtain a MethodInfo. In many cases the name of an action will be the same as the method name on the controller, but this will not always be the case. If you use the ActionName attribute on the controller's method then you can explicitly set the name of the action. In addition, it is possible to have 2 methods with different signatures, both with the same action name. This is common when you have a GET and POST version of the same action (e.g. the Register and LogOn actions present in a brand new ASP.NET MVC project within AccountController.cs).

Comment: The MVC framework itself has no other types that inherit `ActionDescriptor`.

Comment: Indeed. So, you should always get a ReflectedActionDescriptor and my approach will work. I used the word "if" as insurance for future versions of MVC, and to suggest that the code to cast the ActionDescriptor should be written with this possibility in mind.

Comment: I know this is very old, but if you have a Task/Async action method, then it is not ReflectedActionDescription, but TaskAsyncActionDescription.  This could cause problems.

Comment: @DanielLorenz Where is the documentation for TaskAsyncActionDescription, I couldn't find it.

Comment: Nevermind found it at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.async.taskasyncactiondescriptor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

Answer (score 3):

I needed to get the `MethodInfo` to fetch my custom attributes for some logging purposes.

For this specific use case I noticed that (at least in MVC5) an `ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes` method exists, and it's properly overridden for each `ActionDescroptor` descendants.

Similarly, there are other related methods like `GetParameters`, etc.

Comment: In many cases we just need to get `MethodInfo` to get custom attributes, so using this method is cool because we don't need to obtain the `MethodInfo`

Answer (score 2):

Try `Controller.GetType.GetMethod(actionExecutingContext.ActionName)`.

If your code is directly in the action, you could also call `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()`.

Comment: How would the GetMethod solution work where there are multiple methods with the same name? For example, two overloads to LogOn or Register (one accepting POST and the other GET). Also, it's possible to use the ActionName attribute to make the action's name very different to the method name.

Comment: It wouldn't.  Your answer is much better.